# Android AudioTrack stream cuts out early

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to play some looping sound in Android, and I have that going pretty well for me. All good things must come to an end, though, and I would like for that to include my audio loop. However, if I call `AudioTrack.release()` after this loop, as I should, the end of my audio stream gets cut off - there is extra data that I know I'm supposed to hear, but don't.

I've verified this by putting in a Thread.sleep(2000) before the release - the sound plays correctly with that in there. My code looks something like this:

```
// Initialize Audiotrack
int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 2 * minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

mAudioTrack.play();

// Play looping sound
while (stuff) {
    mAudioTrack.write(stuff);
}

// Play one last bit of sound before returning
mAudioTrack.write(lastSound);

// Block until the AudioTrack has played everything we've given it
Thread.sleep(2000); 

// Get rid of the Audiotrack
mAudioTrack.release();
```

I suppose I could leave the Thread.sleep(2000) in there and call it a day, but that sounds messy and irresponsible to me. I'd like to either have a `while()` loop block for the most appropriate amount of time, or use `AudioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener()` and put the `release()` in there.

If I go the first route, I need something to pend on, and `AudioTrack.getPlayState()` appears to always report the track as playing. So I'm stuck there.

If I go the second route, I need a way of getting the position in the AudioTrack buffer that was written to last, so I can tell the AudioTrack what position I'm waiting for it to play up to. I don't have any ideas as to how to get that information, though.

I guess I don't really care which way I do it, so any help towards solving the problem one way or the other would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the buffer size in the AudioTrack.

Imagine the `minBufferSize` is 8k. This means that the AudioTrack will play sound when the buffer is full.

```
mAudioTrack.write(stuff);
```

If `stuff` is only 4K, the AudioTrack will wait until the next call to `write` until it has enough data to play.

**Conclusion**: You need to keep track on how much data you have written, and at the end of your playback feed the AudioTrack with some dummy bytes to complete `minBufferSize`. To make thing easier you could just feed a whole `minBufferSize` amount of silence bytes.

By the way, to feed dummy or silence just fill the data with *zeroes*.

Comment: Writing a `minBufferSize` of zeros looks like it did the trick. I did not know the AudioTrack would only play full buffers; I thought it would continuously advance the playback position in the buffer until it reached the last written position in the buffer. Thanks.